# Unable to get profile information in callback, But able to found that information in serializeUser function

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-github2

I am trying to authenticate a user using passport-github strategy. It seems like everything working fine except I am **unable to fetch profile information inside call back**. But Able to get that information in **serializeUser** function.

```
var configurePassport = {
    configureGithubStrategy : (app) => {

        // STEP 1 : [Initialize passport into the app]

        app.use(passport.initialize())
        app.use(passport.session()); 

        // STEP 2 : [Implement serialize and deserialize objects of passport]

        passport.serializeUser(function(profile,done){
            console.log(`+++ Inside Serialize +++\n${profile.username}\n+++ Note : Able The Get Profile Information +++`)
            done(null,profile);
        })

        passport.deserializeUser(function(profile,done){
            done(null,profile);
        })

        // STEP 3 : [Configure GitHub Strategy]

        passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
            clientID: config.gitHub.clientID,
            clientSecret: config.gitHub.clientSecret,
            callbackURL: config.gitHub.callbackURL
          },
          function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log(`+++ Inside Configuration +++\n${profile}`)
            done(null,profile)
          }
        ));
    }
}
```

```
  const passport = require('passport')
  const configurePassport = require('./config/passportConfig')


  configurePassport.configureGithubStrategy(app)

  app.get('/auth/github',passport.authenticate('github'));


  app.get('/auth/github/callback',passport.authenticate('github',{failureRedirect : '/auth/failed'}),function(request,response){
    console.log(`Unable To Get Profile Information -> ${request.profile}`)
    response.redirect('/profile')    
  })


  app.get('/profile',function(request,response){
    response.status(200).json(request.profile)
  })
```

Inside callback function **request.profile gets undefiend**

Comment: Please checkout my **answer** for this question. If there is anything wrong in it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me If I am wrong, But I found that the **done()** function attaches the profile info on the request object as **user** so it's available on the callback url as **request.user**